# How to use a selector from another feature with NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a page for an administrator where I have a state for that specific page. I also want to show parts of the report state. In the redux devtools I can see I've properly loaded the reports and initialized the admin piece of state, but I can't get my selectors to access the reports piece of the state.

I've went through the official documentation, but separate file multi selectors isn't clear to me ref [official docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors).
I've adjusted my state to inherit from the main state, but that was clearly wrong. I've made some other adjustments and I've been searching google all day long, but so far in vain.

### wageAdmin Part

in the ***admin shell*** component I have

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
// this works
    this.store.dispatch(new fromReportActions.Load());
    this.showReportCode$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromWageAdmin.getShowWageAdminCode)); 

// this returns undefined
    this.reports$ = this.store.pipe(select(queryReports.getReports)); 
    this.errorMessage$ = this.store.pipe(select(queryReports.getError)); 
    this.selectedReport$ = this.store.pipe(select(queryReports.getCurrentReport)); 
    this.displayCode$ = this.store.pipe(select(queryReports.getShowReportCode)); 
  }
```

[image: redux image]

in the ***admin module*** I'm importing

```js
    StoreModule.forFeature('wageAdmins', reducers),
    EffectsModule.forFeature(
      [ WageAdminEffects, ReportEffects ]
    ),
```

in the ***index.ts*** from my admin state i have

```js
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector, ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromRoot from '../../state/app.state';
import * as fromWageAdmin from './wageadmin.reducer';
import * as fromReports from '../../state/report/report.reducer';

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
    wageAdmins: fromWageAdmin.WageAdminState;
}

export const reducers : ActionReducerMap<State> = {
    wageAdmins: fromWageAdmin.reducer,
    reports: fromReports.reducer
}

// Selector functions
export const getWageAdminFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<fromWageAdmin.WageAdminState>('wageAdmins');

export const getShowWageAdminCode = createSelector(
    getWageAdminFeatureState,
    state => state.showReportCode
);
```

in the ***wageadmin.reducer.ts*** i have

```js
import { WageAdminActionTypes, WageAdminActions } from './wageadmin.actions';

// State for this feature (WageAdmin)
export interface WageAdminState {
  showWageAdminCode: boolean;
  wageAdminError: string;
}

const initialWageAdminState: WageAdminState = {
  showWageAdminCode: true,
  wageAdminError: ''
};

export function reducer(state = initialWageAdminState, action: WageAdminActions): WageAdminState {
// etc....
```

### Report Part

In the ***app.state.ts*** file in the top level of my app I have

```js
import * as fromReports from './report/report.reducer';

export interface State {
  reports: fromReports.ReportState
}

export { queryReports } from './report/report.selectors';
export { fromReportActions } from './report/report.actions';
```

in the ***report.reducer.ts*** I have

```js
import { Report } from '../../classes/report';
import { ReportActionTypes, ReportActions } from './report.actions';

// State for this feature (WageAdmin)
export interface ReportState {
  showReportCode: boolean;
  currentReportId: string | null;
  reports: Report[];
  error: string;
}

export const initialState: ReportState = {
  showReportCode: true,
  currentReportId: null,
  reports: [],
  error: ''
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: ReportActions): ReportState {
// etc......
```

In the my ***report.selectors.ts***

```js
import { Transport } from 'src/app/classes/transport';
import { Report } from 'src/app/classes/report';

import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromReports from './report.reducer';

// Selector functions
export const getReportFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<fromReports.ReportState>('reports');
export const getReports = createSelector(
    getReportFeatureState,
    state => state.reports
);
```

### Output

I expected the report state, but I'm getting console error output of

- Cannot read property 'reports' of undefined
- Cannot read property 'showReportCode' of undefined
- Cannot read property 'showReportCode' of undefined
- Cannot read property 'currentReportId' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wrong to combine the reducers at the wageAdmin level.

[image: wrong redux implementation]

I removed ***reducers*** from **index.ts** in wage admin part. Then in the module part I changed the imports to

```js
    StoreModule.forFeature('wageAdmins', reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature(
      [ WageAdminEffects ]
    ),
```

And then in the module where I build the reports, **report.module.ts**, I import the reports store and reducer

```js
    StoreModule.forFeature('reports', reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature(
      [ ReportEffects ]
    ),
```

After this change my code runs as it should
[image: correct redux implementation]